# Devise forgot password submit button works intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

My Devise forgot password button sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. It seems like when I first click the 'forgot password?' link, it doesn't work (button doesn't click), but if I refresh then it's okay.

Here's the production link where this happens (this happens in dev, too): https://www.makerspro.io/users/sign_in

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Here's my view:

```
<body id="homepage">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="card card-outline-secondary" style="width: 42rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Forgot your password?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
              <%= devise_error_messages! %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control" %><br />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>

          <div class="card-footer">
            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/card-body-->
      </div>
      <!-- /form card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And my controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  layout 'pages'

  skip_before_action :read_cookies
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

And my routes:

```
  devise_for :users,
             controllers: { registrations: :registrations,
                            sessions: :sessions,
                            passwords: :passwords,
                            confirmations: :confirmations,
                            unlocks: :unlocks
                          }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without disabling turbolinks?

Comment: It didn't work?